# Passing a string argument, without quotes, into a function in Python

Tags: python, string, function, arguments

I have a Python function where the argument is a string of letters and numbers.

The first function call (after function definition) below works, the second returns an invalid syntax error:

```
def my_function(user):  
     firstNumber=int(user[0])
     secondNumber=int(user[2])
     if user[1]!="d":
          quit()
     else:
          return firstNumber+secondNumber

my_function("5d40")


def my_function(user):  
     firstNumber=int(user[0])
     secondNumber=int(user[2])
     if user[1]!="d":
          quit()
     else:
          return firstNumber+secondNumber

my_function(5d40)
```

How can I gracefully handle (eg. simply quit the program) if a user inputs a string into the argument without quotes, so that I don't get an error?

Comment: without double or single quotes  it is a variable and not a string.

Comment: *Is there any way to accept a string into a function without the surrounding quotes?*   <--- Without surrounding quotes, it's not a string.

Comment: @The6thSense: Not enough, a variable starts with a number is invalid.  :P

Comment: @KevinGuan you got me there :p.

Comment: So if it's not a string,is there no way to avoid a syntax error when a user inputs my_function(5d50)?  A

Comment: Inputs it *how*, exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you have a condition in your function, if the param type is not a string, convert it to string?

Comment: @MapsBySteve `raw_input` will provide strings as the output so you could do `my_function(raw_input())` ther is no need for you to enter quotes when giving input to raw_input

Comment: The way to avoid a syntax error is to use proper syntax. Do you have a reason for not wanting to use proper syntax here?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The function will be used by others besides me, and I would like to gracefully exit the program no matter what the user enters.

Comment: Are you calling `eval`?

Comment: If you meant that the function will be used by others writing Python code, then they must be competent in doing so. By competent, in this case, I mean that they should be expected to know that the second form, above, is a syntax error. You can't deal with it inside your function because the interpreter will never get that far. Maybe you should provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you are hoping to achieve because as you can see from all these comments, it's very unclear currently.

Comment: Your use case of gracefully exiting the program on any user input has no apparent connection to abandoning Python syntax. Please explain why you need to do this.

Comment: If your program actually executes user-provided code, the users should know what they're doing, and you should consider whether you trust them not to be malicious.

Comment: @SiHa I'm new to posting here, thanks for the instruction on how to better my posts.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You're probably right.  It's one of those questions in class which asks me to "handle all bad user input."  But likely the 'user' would know proper syntax.  Thanks to you both and everyone else for your help, if you put your comments in an answer I can upvote them.

Comment: If it's for class, then I can pretty much guarantee that you're getting user input from a standard input function (like Python 2's `raw_input` or Python 3's `input`), in which case that value _is already a string and does not need quotes at all_. You only need quotes when you are entering _string literals_ in source code.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks! I'll close the question.

Comment: Did you try it (e.g. `inp = input('> '); my_function(inp)`) before you posted this question, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for commenting so quickly.

It seems that the answer is, that without quotes around a string argument, it is obviously no longer a string.  Furthermore, I will assume that the user will pass correct python syntax when using the function.